# Two colliding circles , unable to convert formula into code

Tags: c#, wpf, collision

I am at the level where I can detect collision of circles in my rigid body 2D physics program.
These circles have random x, y velocity.
When any of them hits any other of them I can tell that they are colliding against each other then! this step is the problem.
I am trying to take the X and Y values of velocity and convert it based on the axis of collision point, I mean the axis of normal force and another axis that is perpandacular to the normal force axis. The perpandacular axis is called tangent axis... right?

I use sin cos tan, but the problem is that since sin cos tan only returns an angle that is always the right side, my objects never move to the left side.... so the momentum of X axis of all the colliding objects is fixed to the right side.
This leads to whole a lot of problems and I am unable to find out how to fix it.
I would appreciate so much even little piece of advice.
Thank you.

Comment: Try atan2. For Sin and Cos the angle information is already provided.

Comment: little more explanation please...

Comment: atan2 takes both x and y arguments so that no quadrant information is lost dividing them like you would for atan.

Comment: might ask/move this question to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using trigonometric functions (sin, cos, tan, etc.).

You want to apply an impulse to the objects in the direction of the collision, i.e. the impulse is some multiple of the collision direction vector.  Calculate the momentum of the objects and simply add the impulse.

If you're doing simple elastic collisions the momentum and energy are conserved. Given those constraints you can calculate the impulse. [This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) has details.

Comment: impulse? but would I be able to apply this equation still? or should I come up with a whole different ways of processing collision? V1f = ( V1i (m1 - m2 ) + 2 m2V2i )  / (m1+ m2)

Comment: If you're doing simple elastic collisions the momentum and energy are conserved.  Given those constraints you can calculate the impulse.  This wikipedia article has details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision